# Understanding SQL code from an exam

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

I have this question from a previous exam in a DB course.
This question should be answered in 10 minutes in the exam.
I know the rules and the material, but could someone please explain to me how to approach this question ? It's seems so deep and I don't know how to split it into parts and things are getting here so confused.

Thanks a lot.

The question is : What's the output of this code ? 
(Answer : (1,2,2) (3,2,2) )

```
create table T(a int, b int);

insert into T values(1,2);
insert into T values(1,3);
insert into T values(2,4);
insert into T values(3,2);

select T1.a, T1.b, count(*)
from T T1, T T2
where T1.b = T2.b and 
    not exists (select a 
                  from T T3
                  where b not in(select b 
                                 from T T4
                                 where b >= T1.b))
group by T1.a, T1.b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "not exists ..." is a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) and it is evaluated for every row in the result set of the outer select:

```
select T1.a, T1.b, count(*)
from T T1, T T2
where T1.b = T2.b 
--------------------
group by T1.a, T1.b;
```

which returns:

[image: Outer query resut]

Because the value 2 appears twice in T.b, a join on that column produces two rows when b = 2 but only one row for the unique values 3 and 4. Hence the count result.

Every row of the above result is evaluated against the subquery. The innermost select:

```
select b 
from T T4
where b >= T1.b
```

returns a list of T.b where b >= the b of the above result set. If T1.b = 2 the returned list is (2,2,3,4) while T1.b = 3 returns (3,4) and T1.b = 4 returns (4).

Now, if the "middle" query:

```
select a 
from T T3
where b not in (...)
```

doesn't return values for that particular row in the result of the outer query, the row will be shown in the final result set.

Because the innermost query only returns all b values when T1.b = 2, the middle query only returns null when T1.b = 2. Only (1,2,2) and (3,2,2) have T1.b = 2 and they are picked, phew.

Answer (score -1):

Start Inner to Outer.
Have result set of inner query before executing (in your mind) its parent query.
in your question try to understand and solve

```
        select b
        from T T4
        where b >= T1.b
```

now go to its parent... You understood right ????? good.